# Independent NPM library that validates request based on swagger file

Tags: node.js, npm, swagger

We are building APIs using Swagger, AWS API gateway and Lambda functions with NodeJS. The API gateway will do the request validation, however as per the design, the lambda functions need to re-validate the request object as an [API Gateway Proxy Request Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html#eventsources-api-gateway-request). This makes sense as in theory we can reuse the lambda functions by invoking them via other event source (e.g. SNS).

Therefore we need an NodeJS tool which can validate the request (not only body but also params, etc) based on the swagger spec - exactly what the swagger-tools and a few other tools (e.g. [swagger-request-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-request-validator)) are doing, but not as a middleware.

I did some search but could not find one, also looked into swagger-tools source code, reckon its validation component was written in the way that cannot be easily used separately.

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [swagger-model-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-model-validator).

```
var Validator = require('swagger-model-validator');
var swaggerFile = require("./swagger.json");

const validator = new Validator(swaggerFile);

console.log(validator.validate({
    name: 'meg'
}, swaggerFile.definitions.Pet, swaggerFile.definitions, true).GetErrorMessages())
```

This outputs:

> [ 'photoUrls is a required field' ]

`validator.validate` returns an object, so you can also check if the returned object contains anything under the `errors` attribute. It should be as simple as

```
if (validator.validate({
    name: 'meg'
}, swaggerFile.definitions.Pet, swaggerFile.definitions, true).errors) {
    // do something with error
}
```

I have used [Swagger's sample JSON](https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json) for this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it only validates the model (i.e. request body) while `swagger-tools` validates not only request body but also path parameters and query strings.